# Elasticsearch cache

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch

I'm trying to delete a document from `buzz` index in ElasticSearch. Just after deleting I fetch a list of existing entries and deleted item is still in the list.

```
async.series([
function(callback) {
  self._db.DELETE('buzz/news/' + self._id, {}, {}, function(err, response) {
      return callback(err);
  });
},
```

Requesting entry by id states `found:false`

```
function(callback) {
      self._db.GET('buzz/news/' + self._id, {
        v: Date.now()
      }, {}, function(err, result) {
        console.log('result: ', JSON.stringify(result));
        callback(err);
      });
    },
```

Performing a search by criteria still returns this entry in the list.

```
function(callback) {
      self._db.GET('buzz/news/_search', {
        v: Date.now()
      }, qq, function(err, result) {
        console.log('result: ', JSON.stringify(result.hits.hits.map(function(hit) {
          return hit._id;
        })));
        callback(err);
      });
    },], function(err){...});
```

All the code is inside one `async.series`.
Here's the criteria:

```
var qq = {
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "query": {
        "query_string": {
          "fields": ["title"],
          "query": "*"
        }
      },
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [],
          "_cache": false
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "sort": [{
    "pubDate": "desc"
  }],
  "from": "0",
  "size": "30"
}
```

`db.GET` and `db.DELETE` are just wrappera to simple HTTP request.

'Manual' Kibana or Postman reuquests to get entries list after deletion are ok. Item is not in the list. So everything is working correctly, except of, maybe, some 'caching' issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should refresh the indices for the index to be updated before fetching it.

```
client.indices.refresh([params, [callback]])
```